# I'm pleased to hear that you (passed/ have passed) the exam. Which one is right? [ Closed ]

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect

Could you tell me which is the right sentence please?

1. I'm pleased to hear that you passed the exam.
2. I'm pleased to hear that you have passed the exam.

Thanks!

Comment: @Learner please make this question different from previous by adding  details

Comment: If you don't add details to differentiate this question from previous, you won't be answered to this question

Comment: I've found the answer. Thanks for your comment. I'll do that in my next question.